# Looping through all tables in Oracle db and retrieve highest value of primary key for each table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way that I can loop through all the tables in OracleDB using stored procedure and cursor and retrieve the highest value of each primary key value of each table assuming they are of integer type and display them in a row or column?

Comment: You don't actually need a stored procedure or cursors for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join

- `user_constraints`, as it contains information about which constraints are primary keys (`P`)
- `user_cons_columns`, as it contains information about columns involved in those constraints and lets you choose which position that column has in the constraint, if it is a composite key (for simplicity, I used position `1`) and it is used for another join with
- `user_tab_columns` as it contains column datatype

and use a little bit of dynamic SQL, you get something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_max number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in
  5      (select cc.table_name, cc.column_name
  6       from user_constraints uc join user_cons_columns cc on uc.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
  7       join user_tab_columns c on c.table_name = cc.table_name
  8                              and c.column_name = cc.column_name
  9       where uc.constraint_type = 'P'
 10         and cc.position = 1
 11         and c.data_type = 'NUMBER'
 12      )
 13    loop
 14      execute immediate 'select max(' || cur_r.column_name ||') from ' ||
 15                         cur_r.table_name into l_max;
 16      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||' -> max value = '|| l_max);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
DEPT.DEPTNO -> max value = 40
STUDENT.RNO -> max value =
EMPLOY.ID -> max value =
DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID -> max value =
CARS.ID -> max value =
MOVIE.MOV_ID -> max value = 2
ACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_ID -> max value = 3
EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID -> max value =
INF_AUSBAUPLAENE.AUSB_ID -> max value =
EMPLOYEE_NOTES.EMPLOYEE_NOTES_ID -> max value =

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough code and explanation. I really appreciate it!